# Setting indexes right

Tags: postgresql, index

Given following SQL query

```
SELECT dd.* FROM devices_deviceconfiguration_sensors dds
JOIN devices_latest_config dlc ON dlc.config_id = dds.device_configuration_id
JOIN devices_deviceconfiguration dd ON dd.id = dlc.config_id
WHERE dds.sensor_id = $1
```

what is the right way to set indexes to speed up this query? Do I need `dds.sensor_id` indexed or `(dds.sensor_id, dds.device_configuration_id)`?

Query analysis output gives. Avg execution time is 8ms, which is slower than the average queries that we have
[image]

Comment: `dds(sensor_id, device_configuration_id)`, `dlc(config_id)` and `dd(id)`, it seems. Also I'd recommend you to use not `JOIN dlc` but WHERE EXISTS.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain how you would use WHERE EXISTS in this case? dds(sensor_id, device_configuration_id) -> because the sensor_id in the WHERE clause is evaluated first and the JOIN afterwards?

Comment: `SELECT dd.* FROM dd JOIN dds ON dd.id = dds.device_configuration_id WHERE dds.sensor_id = $1 AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM dlc WHERE dlc.config_id = dds.device_configuration_id)`